# Чем открыть файл index в папке кэша firefox?

Tags: linux, bash, кэширование, firefox, index

Как открыть файл ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/профиль/cache2/index ? Открываю в консоли Linux, но видны в основном знаки вопроса. Смотрите скриншот https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4NPw/BY866z8XU [image: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4NPw/BY866z8XU] Пример файла  174Мб https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2Tqv/3UmpmEhwk

Comment: Подозреваю, этот файл в принципе не предназначен для открытия чем-либо

Comment: Приведите картинку в самом вопросе, а не по ссылке (есть специальная кнопка)

Comment: и желательно на каком то популярном сайте, а не на местячковом.

Comment: посмотрел файл у себя - там что то свое (надеялся, то там sqlite, но нет). Видимо нужно брать сорцы фаерфокса и ковырять

Comment: @KoVadim http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html

Comment: круто, люди уже поковыряли и все разобрались